# Show the relation well-orders $S$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

- Let $X$ and $Y$ be two well-ordered sets. Let

$$S=(X\times\left\{0\right\})\cup( Y\left\{1\right\})$$

For all $x,x_1,x_2\in X$ and for all $y,y_1,y_2\in Y$

$(x_1,0)<(x_2,0)$ iff $x_1<x_2,$

$(y_1,1)<(y_2,1)$ iff $y_1<y_2,$

$(x,0)<(y,1)$.

Show the above relation well-orders $S$

My try. Let $U\subseteq (X\times\left\{0\right\})\cup( Y\left\{1\right\})$. If $U\cap (X\times\left\{0\right\})\neq\emptyset$, then define

$$W=\left\{x\in X: (x,0)\in U\right\}$$

$W$ does have a minimal element, say $a$.

If $U\cap (X\times\left\{0\right\})=\emptyset$, then if $U\cap (Y\times\left\{1\right\})\neq\emptyset$, so define

$$V=\left\{y\in Y: (y,1)\in U\right\},$$

$V$ does have a minimal element, say $b$.

**I can't continue. Can you check my try, can you help to continue it? Thanks ...**

Comment: Is $(a,0)$ (risp. $(b,1)$ in the second case) the minimal element of $U$?

Comment: @dcolazin I think yes ??

Comment: Can you prove it? If so, can you conclude that $S$ is a well order?

Comment: @dcolazin, okey i'm trying... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $\langle A,<_R\rangle,\;\langle B,<_S\rangle$ be two well ordered sets such that $A\cap B=\varnothing$. Let $C$ be a nonempty subset of $A\cup B$. We shall prove that it has a minimal element in the sense of the order $<_{R\oplus S}\;=\;<_R\cup<_S\cup\;(A\times B)$

- If $C\cap A\not=\varnothing$, then the minimal element of $C\cap A$ in the sense of $<_R$ is the minimal element of $C$ in the sense of $<_{R\oplus S}$.
- If $C\cap A=\varnothing$, then $C\subseteq B$ and the minimal element of $C$ in the sense of $<_S$ is the minimal element of $C$ in the sense of $<_{R\oplus S}$

Now to your argument. Note how the minimal element of $W$, and $V$ are not the actual minimal elements of $U$ in any of the considered cases, in the sense of the well ordered sum, but $(a,0)$ and $(b,1)$ are, respectively.